# Creating test users using the Facebook C# SDK...?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to create test users for my Facebook application using the Facebook C# SDK.

Not too sure if I'm going about it the right way but here's the code I'm executing...

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(FacebookApplication.Current);
String url = String.Format("/{0}/accounts/test-users", FacebookApplication.Current.AppId);

IDictionary<string, object> userParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();
userParams["installed"] = "true";
userParams["permissions"] = "read_stream";
userParams["access_token"] = AccessToken;

dynamic fbResults = client.Post(url, userParams);
```

I'm receiving an exception...

```
(OAuthException) (#15) The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove userParams["access_token"] = AccessToken;

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(appId, appSecret);
dynamic result = fb.Post(string.Format("{0}/accounts/test-users", appId),
    new { installed = true, permissions = "read_stream" });
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.  Probably should have tried that...!

Comment: I tried doing the same thing but I kept getting that error anyway! Why does that happen?! Check it out please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990051/oauthexception-15-the-method-you-are-calling-must-be-called-with-an-app-secr