# C# equivalent of file_get_contents (PHP)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, inputstream

As a follow-up to [(OAuthException) (#15) The method you are calling must be called with an app secret signed session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990051/oauthexception-15-the-method-you-are-calling-must-be-called-with-an-app-secr) I want to know what is the equivalent of file_get_contents(). I tried the following but I got `illegal characters in path` error.

```
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient(FacebookWebContext.Current);

        var tokenUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + FacebookWebContext.Current.Settings.AppId + "&client_secret=" + FacebookWebContext.Current.Settings.AppSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials";
        var objReader = new StreamReader(tokenUrl);
        string sLine = "";
        var arrayList = new ArrayList();

        while (sLine != null)
        {
            sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
            if (sLine != null)
                arrayList.Add(sLine);
        }
        objReader.Close();
        var appToken = arrayList.ToString();

        dynamic result = fb.Post(string.Format("{0}/accounts/test-users", FacebookWebContext.Current.Settings.AppId),
            new { installed = false, permissions = "read_stream", access_token = appToken });
        return Content(result.ToString());
    }
```

I also tried `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(tokenUrl)` and I got the same error. Is there anything I can do?

I'm not even sure it's going to work, but at least I can try...

Comment: http://www.devprise.com/2006/07/14/c-method-to-mimic-php-file_get_contents/

Comment: That method is heavily outdated

Comment: @Tim, that method claims to with URLs, but checks only for `http:`. So https or ftp wouldn't work.

Comment: you should be using `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @svick: Yup, you're right about https and ftp, I actually added those myself because Facebook uses https now. If you know of a smarter implementation, please do share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use oauth/access_token or any methods related to oauth stuffs use FacebookOAuthClient not FacebookClient or FacebookClient.

```
FacebookOAuthClient.GetApplicationAccessToken(..)
FacebookOAuthClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(..)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. By the way, do you guys plan to put some more documentation on the codeplex page? Some of the docs are outdated I believe? Great work none the less :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) to download text from a URL. The WebClient also [supports authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Also, to split your string into lines you can use:

```
string test;
string[] lines = test.Split('\n');
```

Comment: What a crap implementation in the page you linked to — supports only HTTP, assumes everything else is a local file, and assumes the most ancient and unhelpful encoding in existence (namely ASCII)!

Comment: The original poster is using http(s) and the encoding returned by the web site is used. This is a very easy to use implementation.